# Problema con arrays dentro de bucle for

Tags: c++, sfml

estoy haciendo un motor de físicas 2D, y por ahora estoy programando las colisiones círculo a círculo. Vaya que es complicado (pero fácil). Estoy ahora mismo comprobando si calculé correctamente cuando colisionan, y para eso necesito moverlos con el mouse para hacerlos colisionar, pero al tratar de saber sobre cual círculo esta el mouse, la función no compila:

```
int mouseTouchingBall(sf::Vector2i mouseCoords, ball* balls)
{
    int currentBallCoords[2];
    int triangleWidth = 0;
    int triangleHeight = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        currentBallCoords = {ball[i].positionX + ((ball[i].radius * 2) / 2), ball[i].positionY + ((ball[i].radius * 2) / 2)}; // error

        if (mouseCoords.x < currentBallCoords[0])
        {
            triangleWidth = currentBallCoords[0] - mouseCoords.x;
        }else if (mouseCoords.x > currentBallCoords[0])
        {
            triangleWidth = mouseCoords.x - currentBallCoords[0];
        }

        if (mouseCoords.y < currentBallCoords[1])
        {
            triangleHeight = currentBallCoords[1] - mouseCoords.y;
        }else if (mouseCoords.y > currentBallCoords[1])
        {
            triangleHeight = mouseCoords.y - currentBallCoords[1];
        }
    }
}
```

La función no está completa, nisiquiera tiene el return, porque todavía la estaba escribiendo cuando me salió el error. Recuerdo que ya he obtenido problemas con un array en bucle for, poniendo como índice la variable I, alguna solución? necesitan el código completo?

Answer (score 0):

Tu error es fácilmente reproducible con este código:

```
int i[2];
i = { 0, 0 }; // Error.
```

Las formaciones<sup>1</sup> no pueden ser reinicializadas, tus alternativas son asignar miembro a miembro:

```
currentBallCoords[0] = ball[i].positionX + ((ball[i].radius * 2) / 2);
currentBallCoords[1] = ball[i].positionY + ((ball[i].radius * 2) / 2);
```

O usar [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
std::array<int, 2> currentBallCoords;
currentBallCoords = {ball[i].positionX + ((ball[i].radius * 2) / 2), ball[i].positionY + ((ball[i].radius * 2) / 2)}; // Ok
```

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

Comment: Creo que la solucion de la biblioteca estándar para este problema no es `std::array<int,2>` sino `std::pair<int,int>`, que también puede recibir el tipo de asignaciones que él intenta, pero tiene un uso más específico para pares ordenados.

Comment: @D4RIO No hay una solución estándar para la detección de colisión entre dos circulos. Si te refieres a una solución estándar para almacenar dos elementos, tampoco hay una, ya que dependiendo de la situación necesitarás una formación, una tupla, un par, dos punteros, dos variables, una unión, o un objeto personalizado.

Comment: Voy a probar, pero me parece que ya habia intentado lo de reasignar miembro por miembro

Comment: @Programen lo que te propongo solucionará tu problema de compilación (que es lo que motivó tu pregunta) lo que no resolverá es tu algoritmo de colisión de círculos, que no veo que vaya por buen camino...

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster es evidente que si propongo `std::pair<>` no me refiero a la detección de colision entre circulos. El que haya varias soluciones que funcionan no las hace a todas estándar. Un par ordenado tiene su solucion estándar en `std::pair` porque es más ligero que una tupla o un array, que tienen funciones innecesarias para un par, y porque punteros, variables y clases personalizadas son alternativas a una solución disponible en la biblioteca estándar. Algunas de esas están explícitamente desrecomendadas en la bibliografía de referencia del lenguaje.

Comment: No has visto el algoritmo completo, eso solo es una funcion para mover el circulo con el mouse, luego programare para aplicarle fuerza, inercia, etc... Por cierto, ya lo hice, pero lo que hace es decirme "expected primary expression before [ token"

Comment: Hola, me dí cuenta que la [ del error es la de [i]

Comment: ALV mucha gueba, estaba poniendo ball y no balls. XD

Comment: @D4RIO "*el que haya varias soluciones que funcionen no las hace a todas estándar*" puedo comprarte ese argumento (aunque el estándar en este contexto no tiene nada que ver) pero el que una solución forme parte del estándar no la hace válida para todos los casos. A ti te ha parecido que un par es lo ideal para guardar dos datos, pero lo ideal para guardar dos datos no depende ni de ti ni del estándar, depende de la situación.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, 100% de acuerdo, pero lo estándar y lo ideal son cosas muy distintas. Para soluciones ideales prefiero C, que es más cercano a la solución. C++ está orientado a una mejor descripción del problema, por eso la bibliografía recomienda en lo posible mantenerse en las soluciones estándar (de las que se proveen muchas), y por eso aconsejo ir a la solución estándar. Cuanto más avancen los compiladores, más se deberían optimizar las soluciones estándar vigentes.

Comment: El que una solución sea *estándar* aquí no tiene nada que ver. ¿Por qué iba a ser mejor un `std::pair` que una formación de dos elementos? No se sabe... si esos dos elementos deben iterarse o accederse mediante indizado el `std::pair` no servirá. Si la situación es otra ¿Quién sabe?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, si no mencionás, no me notifica. En mi 1er comentario me referí a "*la solucion de la biblioteca estándar*", porque usaste `std::array`, de ahí en adelante vengo hablando de que sea la solución de la biblioteca _estándar_. Ese es todo el motivo por el que hablé de `std::pair`. Si hablamos de "mejor" o "ideal", en este caso voto por `struct`, porque ni arrays ni pairs proveen semántica de lo que contienen. `coords[0]`, o `coords.first` no son más legibles que `coords.x`. Hacerla miembro de `balls` cambiando `ball[i].positionX` por `ball[i].coord.x` también es más coherente.